# Comparing values returned by query to another query to see if they exist in both

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm writing a query that needs to check if the results of one query (each distinct value) don't exist in another query (that queries distinct values).

For example,

If Query1 results are like: (1, 2, 3, 4) and Query2 results are (1, 2, 5), I need to return a fail message that I've written.

In another example, if Query1 results are something like: (1, 1, 1, 2, 3) and Query2 results are: (1, 2, 3), then I won't return a message.

Currently, I've ran the query using a TOP 1, but that only checks to see if the top records are equal.  How would I go through to check that each result is matching? If I can use a COUNT function to do it, that would be really beneficial as well.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @result = t1.result FROM results t1 WHERE t1.id LIKE '%00%'
SELECT TOP 1 @result2 = t1.result FROM results t1 WHERE t1.id LIKE '%11%'

IF ISNULL(@result, '') <> ISNULL(@result, '') 
PRINT 'ERROR'
```

I've been able to use a COUNT with and EXCEPT to check if they match.  However, I'm not sure if the result is correct or if it's what I'm looking for.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results t1 WHERE t1.id LIKE '%00%'
EXCEPT 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM results t1 WHERE t1.id LIKE '%11%'
```

Comment: Why count? just check if EXCEPT is empty twice

Answer (score 0):

Using *Except* would seem appropriate, if I understand your question, but you don't want to compare the counts, you want to compare the rows, perhaps something like

```
select Result = case when exists (
    select distinct <col> from results where...
    except
    select distinct <col> from results where...
) then 'Error' else 'No error' end;
```

I'm not sure if you need to be "2-way" but you might also want to union the opposite too.